# How can I obtain a file handle from its fileno in Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'm working with a Perl script that uses [threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) and [threads::shared](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html). I want to read from a file handle that is opened by a separate thread, but [threads::shared](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html) can't admit it as a value for a shared scalar.

I'm thinking maybe I can simply share the result of [fileno](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html) to the other thread and then have it read it. The problem is that I don't know what to do with that number. If the answer is in the documentation, I'm probably not searching for the right thing as I haven't found it yet. **How can I get an actual file handle from its [fileno](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html) value?**

If that's not possible, is there a way to open and pass a file handle to another thread after both threads are created?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: did you open the file with the modern approach? open my $file, '<', 'filename'

Comment: Yes. Then I get the value from `fileno($file)` and pass it to a different thread.

Comment: this may helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696375/perl-share-filehandle-with-threads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> If you specify `'<&=X'`, where `X` is a file descriptor number or a filehandle, then Perl will do an equivalent of C's `fdopen` of that file descriptor

```
my $fileno = 0;
open(my $stdin, "<&=$fileno");   # 2-argument form
open(my $stdin, "<&=", $fileno); # or use 3-argument form
```

If you prefer an object-oriented approach, you can use [IO::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::File) and the [`fdopen`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Handle#io-fdopen-FD-MODE) or [`new_from_fd`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Handle#new_from_fd-FD-MODE) methods (as Borodin pointed out):

```
use IO::File;
my $stdin = IO::File->new_from_fd($fileno, 'r');
```

Answer (score 3):

As @cjm has said, you need to call `fdopen` on the file number.

But it is much more straightforward and more readable to use the `fdopen` method from [`IO::Handle`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO::Handle).

It looks like this

```
my $fh = IO::File->new;
$fh->fdopen($fileno, 'r');
```

and note that [`IO::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO::File) (which subclasses `IO::Handle`) is loaded on demand with Perl 5 version 14 and later, so you don't need to `use IO::File` unless you have a very old Perl installation.